# Batch File Copy With Undefined Destination

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

So I have been searching around for the answer here and am not able to find it. I'm not by any means well-versed with coding these sorts of things so excuse my noobishness.

So I am trying to create a simple batch file for deployment with a backup device for the end user to double-click and copy their profile folder to the backup media.

I am not certain if `xcopy` or `robocopy` is the best solution for this, but coming from server administration I am more familiar with `robocopy`. The copy utility I'm using isn't necessarily the problem, however.

What I have:

```
robocopy D:\%USERPROFILE% <destination> /e /copyall
```

While the source resolves to the user profile without issue, I have not been able to derive a variable for the destination that could account for the possibility of different from letters, which I don't think is possible. Is there a variable that sets the destination as the location from where the batch file is launched?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a variable that sets the destination as the location from
>   where the batch file is launched?

yes, there is:

```
echo %~dp0
```

this gives you **D**rive and **P**ath of your batchfile. For more `~.`modifiers see `call /?`